# Stuck inside an infinite loop when adding a node in linked list

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, infinite-loop, singly-linked-list

I've been struggling to figure out why this code is stuck in an infinite loop. The back story is I have found the solution, I changed the constructor to assign head is equal to null and that fixed it.

I wonder why this code is NOT working.

When I add different nodes, it is working. The code works as expected.

Issues arise when adding the same node.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node one = new Node(1);
        Node two = new Node(2);

        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(one);
        // this gives error, if i add the same nodes
        list.add(two);
        list.add(two);

        System.out.println("Printing out:\n" + list.toString() +"\n");
    }
}


public class LinkedList {
    Node head;
    int length = 0;
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (head==null);
    }

    public String toString() {
        Node current = head;
        String string = "Head: ";

        while(current.next != null) {
            string += current.toString() + " --> ";
            current = current.next;
        }
        string += current.toString() + " --> " + current.next;
        return string;
    }

    public LinkedList(Node node) {
        // if were to set head to null and no arg, it works fine
        head = node;
        length = 1;
    }

    public void add(Node node) {
        if(isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty list, adding node...");
            head = new Node(node.data); ++length;
            return;
        }
        else {

        Node current = head;
        while(current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        //current.next = new Node(node.data);
        current.next = node;
        ++length;
        return;
        }
    }
```

The error is, it never terminates, hence why I think it is forever looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your add(Node node) code. When you adding same node twice, it will point the next to itself. Therefore it would be infinite loop.

Comment: I am uncertain if that's right, please explain more. When I make the changes so that the code WORKS as expected, it does not give me an infinite loop.

Comment: Actually, very interesting. After setting the constructor for LinkedList class, -- public LinkedList() { head = null; length = 0;}, the code will be able to add twice of the same node, -- Node two = new Node(2); LinkedList list = new LinkedList(); list.add(two); list.add(two); ...that works. It will print 2--> 2--> null. When I add a third one of the same node, it goes to loop forever again.

Comment: I think you are right, I just can't wrap my head around it, but this may be the case. Please explain a little more :)

Comment: I think the problem is still the same. In case you add new constructor, i think here is what happened in your new code:

1. First time you added two, `head = new Node(node.data);` This will create new Node as Head.

2. Second time you added two, because it is different object with the head (the head is new object). So, you fine here

3. The third time, you added two. Two object already exist in you list. Therefore second and third element will pointing next to each other, which actually the same object

Comment: I think to ensure this won't happen. You can change the add(Node node) to become add(int data). Inside this you should new a Node with provided data.

Comment: Have you fixed or fully understand your problem yet?

Comment: Wow yes, this makes a whole lot of sense. I understand it conceptually. Wrapping up, though I'm adding the same node, why do they point at each other and not to null?

Answer (score 1):

Its going in infinte loop because of while loop in toString() method of LinkedList class.

you are validating on condition

```
while(current.next != null) { .....}
```

after reaching on last node, you are not setting next of last node to null, so the condition will never terminate.

To resolve this where you are adding node point node.next = null;

```
        current.next = node;
        node.next = null;
        ++length;
        return;
```

It will terminate and will not go in infinte loop

Comment: I have made the change in code, and though it does not go on to do a forever loop, it does not add the second node.

Answer (score 1):

The line in your code not fine is in add method ‘current.next=node’ . Try to change it to ‘current.next=new Node(node.data)’